# What does "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" Mean?

Tags: c++, winforms, command-line-interface

Whenever My form 1 tries to open form 2 I get this error...

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

What does this mean? Here is the Code I use for opening Form2...

```
if (TimerValue == 5000)
         {
             this -> timer1 -> Stop();
             TimerValue = 0;
             Form2 ^ f2 = gcnew Form2;
             f2->Show();
             MoviePlay = 1;
             StreamWriter^ outFile = gcnew StreamWriter("Movie.txt");
             String^ Movie = MoviePlay.ToString();
             outFile->Write(Movie);
             outFile->Close();
             this -> button4 ->Visible = false;
             this -> button5 ->Visible = false;
             this -> label2 ->Visible = false;
             this -> button2 ->Visible = false;
             this -> button3 ->Visible = false;
             FriendString = File::ReadAllText(".\\Rca13\\Friend.txt");
             Friend = System::Convert::ToInt32(FriendString);
             if (Friend == 1)
             {
             this -> pictureBox1 -> Load("RetaliationBackground1_Pony1");
             }
             if (Friend == 2)
             {
             this -> pictureBox1 -> Load("RetaliationBackground1_Pony2");
             }
             if (Friend == 3)
             {
             this -> pictureBox1 -> Load("RetaliationBackground1_Pony3");
             }
             if (Friend == 4)
             {
             this -> pictureBox1 -> Load("RetaliationBackground1_SwagMasta");
             }

         }
```

Is there anything that was put into this code causing the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I suspect the problem is this:

```
Friend = System::Convert::ToInt32(FriendString);
```

My guess is that `FriendString` isn't a valid integer. If this is user input, you should probably use `Int32.TryParse` so that you can detect this without resorting to exceptions.

It's important to learn to read stack traces to see which method has failed and the last place in *your* code that's mentioned... and then diagnose the prolem further.

Comment: Any idea why? I did claim it as a variable at the top by saying String^ FriendString;

Comment: @DevonThomas: Yes, but what do you expect it to do if the value is "Fred"? That's not an integer.

Comment: I thought that the command was supposed to go like this...  IntName = System::Convert::ToInt32(NameOfString); I thought this would convert the string into a number and transfer it into a integer... Am i mistaken?

Comment: It will convert a valid string representation of a number (specifically an interger), i.e. `"23"`, `"6234"`, `"92479"`, or `"0"`. If the value of the string is `"Fred"`, the method cannot turn it into a integer because `"Fred"` is not a sequence of characters that represent numbers, but rather letters. It would be the same as asking you what number does `"A"` represents...